# Floating number comparing in tcl

Tags: math, floating-point, tcl

I am getting problems when I calculating distance between point and line.
There is floating point number calculation (compare expression) problem. Due to this I not able to know perfect value of $onextensionFlag. please see following...
May I know what is wrong?

```
proc calculateDistanceToLinefrompoint {P line} {
# solution based on FAQ 1.02 on comp.graphics.algorithms
# L = sqrt( (Bx-Ax)^2 + (By-Ay)^2 )

#     (Ay-Cy)(Bx-Ax)-(Ax-Cx)(By-Ay)
# s = -----------------------------
#                 L^2
# dist = |s|*L # =>
#        | (Ay-Cy)(Bx-Ax)-(Ax-Cx)(By-Ay) |
# dist = ---------------------------------
#                       L
# (Ay-Cy)(Ay-By)-(Ax-Cx)(Bx-Ax)
# r = -----------------------------
                # L^2
# r=0      P = A
# r=1      P = B
# r<0      P is on the backward extension of AB
# r>1      P is on the forward extension of AB
# 0<=r<=1    P is interior to AB

set ret 0
set Ax [lindex $line 0 0]
set Ay [lindex $line 0 1]
set Az [lindex $line 0 2]

set Bx [lindex $line 1 0]
set By [lindex $line 1 1]
set Bz [lindex $line 1 2]

set Cx [lindex $P 0]
set Cy [lindex $P 1]
set Cz [lindex $P 2]

if {$Ax==$Bx && $Ay==$By && $Az==$Bz} {
    set ret [list [GetDistanceBetweenTwoPoints $P [lindex $line 0]] 1] 
} else {
    set L [expr {sqrt(pow($Bx-$Ax,2) + pow($By-$Ay,2) + pow($Bz-$Az,2))}]
    #puts "L=$L"
    set d_val [expr {($Ay-$Cy)*($Bx-$Ax)-($Ax-$Cx)*($By-$Ay)-($Az-$Bz)*($Az-$Cz)}]
    set n_rval [expr {$d_val / pow($L,2)}]
    set n_rval [format "%0.3f" $n_rval]

    if { 0 < $n_rval && $n_rval < 1} {
        set onextensionFlag 0;# inside clipping area
    } elseif {$n_rval == 0 || $n_rval == 1} {
        set onextensionFlag 1 ;# inside clipping area (but on point)
    } elseif { $n_rval > 1 || $n_rval < 0 } {
        set onextensionFlag 2 ;# outside clipping area
    } else {
        set onextensionFlag 3 ;# consider inside clipping area
    }

    set ret [list [expr {abs($d_val) / $L}] $onextensionFlag $n_rval]


     }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point numbers (in all languages, not just Tcl) represent most numbers somewhat inexactly. As such, they should not normally be compared for equality as that's really rather unlikely. Instead, you should check to see if the two values are within a certain amount of each other (the amount is known as *epsilon* and takes into account that there are small errors in floating point calculations).

In your code, you might write this:

```
set epsilon 0.001; # Small, but non-zero
if { $epsilon < $n_rval && $n_rval < 1-$epsilon} {
    set onextensionFlag 0;# inside clipping area
} elseif {abs($n_rval) < $epsilon || abs(1-$n_rval) < $epsilon} {
    set onextensionFlag 1 ;# inside clipping area (but on point)
} elseif { $n_rval >= 1+$epsilon || $n_rval <= -$epsilon } {
    set onextensionFlag 2 ;# outside clipping area
} else {
    set onextensionFlag 3 ;# consider inside clipping area
}
```

Basically, think in terms of a number line where you change points to small intervals:

```
                0                1
————————————————|————————————————|————————————————
```

to

```
             0-ε 0+ε          1-ε 1+ε
———————————————(—)——————————————(—)———————————————
```

How to do the checks for which range you're in then follow from that.

Comment: thanks. This is what I was looking for. very good lesson for me.

Comment: Also, in IEEE floating point (which Tcl uses) the numbers which *are* exact are the whole numbers up to quite a reasonable size. But not infinitely; double precision floats have a fixed number of bits.